# How to skip/handle an empty-sheet/No-sheet in R Excel Automation?

Tags: r, excel, automation

I am trying to merge/bind a huge set of data. The code for that is written and working fine. The problem comes while trying to combine data where there is no sheet present. Is there any ways by which I can skip the error?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xlsx)

files <- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx")

read_Sheet_1 <- lapply(files, readxl::read_excel, sheet = "Sheet 1")
Sheet_1 = do.call(rbind, read_Sheet_1) 

read_Sheet_2 <- lapply(files, readxl::read_excel, sheet = "Sheet 2")
Sheet_2 = do.call(rbind, read_Sheet_2)

read_Sheet_3 <- lapply(files, readxl::read_excel, sheet = "Sheet 3")
Sheet_3 = do.call(rbind, read_Sheet_3) 

write.xlsx(as.data.frame(Sheet_1), file="Final.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet_1", row.names=FALSE)
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(Sheet_2), file="Final.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet_2", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(Sheet_3), file="Final.xlsx", sheetName="Sheet_3", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Expected Result: Merged rows from each sheets in one Final.xlsx file
Actual Result: Even though the functions merges the rows together. Error comes if there is just 2 sheets in one of the file. Example: File3.xlsx has just "Sheet 1" and "Sheet 3" in it, not "Sheet 2". So this will throw an error for entire "Sheet_2" data frame.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `safely` from the `purrr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xlsx)

files <- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx")

read_excel_safe <- function(file, sheet) {
  read_excel_safely <- safely(readxl::read_excel, otherwise = NULL)
  read_excel_safely(file, sheet = sheet)$result
}

Sheet_1 <- files %>% 
  map(.f = read_excel_safe, sheet = 'Sheet 1') %>% 
  reduce(rbind)
```

The function `read_excel_safely` will return a named list with error and results. If there is an error, result will be `NULL`. And it should affect the `rbind` when performing that reduce step.